# Typescript: No warning using wrong parameter count

Tags: typescript, tslint

I´m currently using Typescript 3.6.4.

Code:

```
const a = () => {
  console.log("what ever");
}
const b = (aprop:(aparam:string)=> void) => {
  aprop("myparam");
}
const c = () => {
  b(a)
};

c()
```

Somehow TS is not showing any error compiling this. Although "a" doesn't take a parameter "b" can savely call "a" with a parameter.

But this would throw an error (Expected 0 arguments, but got 1):

```
const a=()=>{
    console.log("what ever")
}

const b=()=>{
    a("x");
}
```

It looks like a bug to me but maybe there is something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### updated

```
const a: (a: string) => void = () => {
    console.log("no matter");
}
```

see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions

### old

`() => void` is compatible with `(a:string) => void`, because the former function doesn't need an parameter.
The parameter won't be used when the function is called, it won't cause error any more.